# adjoint functor of inverse image functor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra, complex-geometry

$f: U\hookrightarrow X$ an open immersion of two complex manifolds. $f^{-1}$ is inverse image functor, in usual sense, from category of sheaves of abelian groups $\mathcal{Ab}(X)$ over $X$ to category of sheaves of abelian groups $\mathcal{Ab}(U)$ over $U$.

The question is: does $f^{-1}$ has left adjoint functor $f_!$ which is extension by zero?(Note that we are considering Category of sheaves of abelian groups instead of category of $\mathcal{O}_X$ or $\mathcal{O}_Y$ modules)

Comment: Yes, and more generally for an open subset $U$ of a topological space $X$ (see Iversen, Cohomology of sheaves, p. 110), or am I missing something here?